# There is a way to load Webpack modules with SystemJS?

Tags: webpack, systemjs, auth0

I am building an Angular 2 application with SystemJS. And I am using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) to make authentication. Auth0 come with auth0-lock which is packaged as Webpack module. There is any way to load it with SystemJS ?

Comment: There is no special form of a webpack module. Webpack creates CommonJS modules. [SystemJS can import CommonJS modules](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs), so this should absolutely be possible.

Comment: Ok. I suppose I don't understand something. Distribution of auth0-lock contains file webpack.config.js. And lib folder contains a file index.js.

Comment: This index.js file contains something looking like exports :
exports.__esModule = true;

Comment: How can I import this with SystemJS ?